# Running exe on 32/64 work with ACE-Driver

Tags: .net, ms-access, office-interop, ms-jet-ace

i want to run **ONE** exe on a 32b / 64b OS. I use the VS-settings x86 to use the wow64 mode. The exe work with no erros.

Now i want to start to support office 2010 with 32b and 64b, i decided to use the "Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable". There are two different versions 32b and 64b it depends on the installed office which you need.

For example, if Win7 64b, Office 2010 64b and 64b drivers are installed. The application runs in wow64 and should use the 64 driver. Everytime i get an error that the driver is not found.

Is it possible to go like i want it or do i need to create two different exe files?

Comment: A very good question, since, apparently, [the 32b and 64b version of the Access DB Engine Redistributable cannot coexist on the same machine](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/abf34eea-1029-429a-b88e-4671bffcee76), and so you *have* to use the 64-bit driver if the user has Office 2010 64 installed. Maybe using the old, purely 32-bit, pre-installed `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` driver would be an alternative?

Comment: I think about that, but if there is an office 2010 64b, jet doesnt work anymore. I tried this scenario in a vm. Check my answer how i solved my problem. thank you for your support!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So like heinzi said its impossible to install both versions. I found a way to get both installed, but for customers its not a possibility, its *to hacky*

http://blog.codefluententities.com/2011/01/20/microsoft-access-database-engine-2010-redistributable/

I'm forced of microsoft to make two exe-files. So i decided to do this, but with one setup and  a manager who choose the 32b or 64b exe. The advantage is, there are no changes in the process to run the application.